# Tracing a SQL Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, debugging, iis

I have a SQL Exception that occurs on a client's production server (in which I have little rights).

I cannot replicate the problem locally but is there any good way to get and figure out what sql exception is being called and with which sql?  I can redeploy and have access to changing the source code.

My stack trace is like this:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace:
[SqlException (0x80131904):  ]

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1950954
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846939
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CloseInternal(Boolean closeReader) +169
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close() +96
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +292
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() +139
Output.RunTable(String outputType, String _outputDataType) +1106
Output.ProcessPage() +33
Output.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +6466
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Comment: I believe the Exception message and it's inner exceptions messages can he help you a lot more than this...

Comment: how do i know where to grab the exception message from?

Comment: The error message returned from SQL Server is in the *inner exception* of the inner exception of the SqlException (3 levels deep)... so you'll want to use `exception.GetBaseException().Message` to get the SQL Server error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the following approach to collect more information about the exception (taken from MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)):

```
    try
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
        {
            errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks i was looking for help like this :)